# UIPopover Controller dismissal

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uipopovercontroller

I have a doubt.

When dismissing a Popover Controller does the `initWithContentViewController` object gets released? For Example:

```
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
```

Does the content gets released here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. initWithContentsViewController increments the retain count by 1, ARC or non-ARC. Dismissing the popOver will decrement the retain count by 1.